# Controlling terminal and GDB

Tags: c, linux, terminal, gdb, pty

I have a Linux process running in the background. I want to take over its stdin/out/err over SSH and also be the terminal controller. The "original" file descriptors are pseudo terminals, too.
I have tried Reptyr and [dupx](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/). Reptyr fails around vfork, but dupx works very well. The GDB script it generated:

```
attach 123
set $fd=open("/dev/pts/14", 0)
set $xd=dup(0)
call dup2($fd, 0)
call close($fd)
call close($xd)
set $fd=open("/dev/pts/14", 1089)
set $xd=dup(1)
call dup2($fd, 1)
call close($fd)
call write($xd, "Remaining standard output of 123 is redirected to /dev/pts/14\n", 62)
call close($xd)
set $fd=open("/dev/pts/14", 1089)
set $xd=dup(2)
call dup2($fd, 2)
call close($fd)
call write($xd, "Remaining standard error of 123 is redircted to /dev/pts/14\n", 60)
call close($xd)
```

As soon as the dupx command finished, the shell is not returned and the target app receives my input (via pts/14) immediately.

Now I want to achieve the same result using my standalone binary application. I've ported the same syscalls (dup/dup2/close, etc) what being executed by the gdb by script driven by dupx:

```
int fd; int xd;
char* s = "Remaining standard output is redirected to new terminal\n";

fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
xd = dup( STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(fd,  STDIN_FILENO );
close(fd);
close(xd);

fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND);
xd = dup( STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd,  STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd);
write(xd, s, strlen(s));
close(xd);

fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND);
xd = dup( STDERR_FILENO);
dup2(fd,  STDERR_FILENO);
close(fd);
write(xd, s, strlen(s));
close(xd);
```

Running the snipplet above is done by injecting a shared library into the remote process via sigstop/ptrace attach/dlopen/etc (using a tool similar to hotpatch). Lets consider this part of the problem to be safe and working reliable: after doing all this, the file descriptors of the target process are changed as I wanted. I can verify it by simply checking /proc/`pidof target`/fd.

However, the shell returns and it still receives all my input, not the target app.

I noticed if I simply attach/detach with gdb after this point (= fds changed by the injected C code) without actually changing anything, the desired behavior is accomplished (mean: the shell is not returned but the target app starts receiving my input). The command is:

```
gdb --pid=`pidof target` --batch --ex=quit
```

And now my question is: how? What happens in the background? How can I do the same without gdb? I've tried stracing gdb to get some hints, and also tried playing with the tty ioctl API's without any luck.

Please note, that obtaining the terminal controller status (if that is the key of this problem at all) by the fork/setsid way what Reptyr uses is not acceptable for me: I want to avoid forking.
Additionally, I cant control starting the target, so "why don't you run it in screen" is no answer here.

Comment: You wrote _As soon as the dupx command finished, the shell is not returned and the target app receives my input (via pts/14) immediately._ Where did you get this `pts/14` from? If it is the terminal of your shell, then after the `dupx` the shell and the _target app_ are competing for the input from `pts/14`, with hardly predictable results.

Comment: I've ssh access, thats where pts/14 was coming from. Shell and the target app might be competing, but I've never experienced such behaviour; dupx alwaysed did what I wanted in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> I've ssh access, thats where pts/14 was coming from. Shell and the
>   target app might be competing, but I've never experienced such
>   behaviour; dupx alwaysed did what I wanted in this scenario.

Well, sitting and wondering why the known problem by chance didn't show up in the past won't solve it, even if this point would be clarified. The way to go is to make it work by design rather than by accident. For this purpose it is necessary for your *standalone binary application* to not return to the shell (to avoid the concurrent reading of input) while the input is supposed to go to the *target app*.
See e. g. also [Redirect input from one terminal to another](https://superuser.com/questions/145605/redirect-input-from-one-terminal-to-another), [Why does tapping a TTY device only capture every other character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179994/why-does-tapping-a-tty-device-only-capture-every-other-character)